# How to get/set a global variable (BOOL) from within a background-thread? (Xcode)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, xcode, ios

From my main thread, I launch an image loader method **method-A** (below). The problem is, if **method-A** is not finished at the time a new **method-A** call is made, image loading starts from the beginning.

What I want to do is, nullify any *new* **method-A** calls that are made while a *previous* **method-A** call is still doing work... The way I (attempt to) do it now is having a simple global BOOL variable (BOOL imageLoaderBusy) and using it to keep track if the **method-A** is still working or not (as shown below).

The problem is, the variable seems to be ignored sometimes, and new **method-A** calls are undesirably started...I dunno. Maybe there is a special way you need to create global variables to make them accessible / valid across multiple threads?

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
//Method-A called like this:

[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadPagesWithGraphics:) withObject:nil];


//Method-A

-(IBAction)loadPagesWithGraphics:(id)sender{

    NSAutoreleasePool *arPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    if(!imageLoaderBusy){

    imageLoaderBusy = YES;

        // Load Images

        }

       imageLoaderBusy = NO;

       [arPool release];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that your variable shouldn’t be global. It should be an instance variable since your method is an instance method and image loading probably refers to images stored/referenced by an instance.

Comment: @Bavarious thanks for this info because I still lack a clear understanding on the exact mechanics of variables and multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this way:

```
-(IBAction)loadPagesWithGraphics:(id)sender{
    if( imagesDidLoad )  return;

    @synchronized(self) {

       NSAutoreleasePool *arPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        // Load Images

       [arPool release];

       //set global ivar
       imagesDidLoad = YES;
   }
}
```

and in Method-A

add

```
-(void) methodA {
    if( !imagesDidLoad )
       [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadPagesWithGraphics:) withObject:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hi max, thanks for your quick answer. Could you please elaborate on what this @synchronized(self) does for my method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554270/iphone-use-of-mutexes-with-asynchronous-url-requests

Comment: basically @synchronized(self) blocks the method for all other threads

Comment: Thanks max. This helped greatly.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of a variable being an instance variable or a global variable, if multiple threads may write to that variable concurrently, you need to lock that section of code. For instance,

```
-(IBAction)loadPagesWithGraphics:(id)sender{
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (imageLoaderBusy) return;
        imageLoaderBusy = YES;
    }

    NSAutoreleasePool *arPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    // Load Images
    imageLoaderBusy = NO;
    [arPool release];
}
```

Let’s say two executions of that method happen simultaneously in threads A and B, and A gets the lock first, so thread B waits for the lock to be released. From A’s perspective, `imageLoaderBusy == NO` so it doesn’t return, sets `imageLoaderBusy = YES`, and releases the lock.

Since the lock has been released, thread B can start executing. It checks `imageLoaderBusy` and, since thread A has set it to `YES`, the method returns immediately in thread B.

Thread A proceeds to load the images and sets `imageLoaderBusy` to `NO`.

Note that this means that if the method is called again in some thread it will be executed and load the images *again*. I’m not sure if that’s your intended behaviour; if it’s not, you’ll need another check to determine if images have already been loaded. For instance,

```
-(IBAction)loadPagesWithGraphics:(id)sender{
    if (imagesHaveBeenLoaded) return;

    @synchronized(self) {
        if (imageLoaderBusy) return;
        imageLoaderBusy = YES;
    }

    NSAutoreleasePool *arPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    // Load Images
    [arPool release];

    imageLoaderBusy = NO; // not strictly necessary
    imagesHaveBeenLoaded = YES;
}
```

You don’t need to have all the method inside a `@synchronize` block. In fact, critical sections should usually be kept small, especially if the lock is being applied to the whole object (`self`). If the entire method were a critical section, thread B would have to wait until all images are loaded before noticing that another thread was already busy/had already loaded the images.

Answer (score 1):

in `Method-a` call a setter on you're main thread to set that `BOOL`.

The method to do that is : `- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait`

Comment: thanks for the quick answer Thomas. That covers setting. What about the getting of the variable? Or can that just be done as-is?

Comment: I guess that's possible as-is. You'd have to be careful about deadlocking (multiple threads accessing the same ivar), which is solvable by NSLock. I don't know much about you're app, but if you want to set ivars from a thread as well as getting them, you'll have a lot of issues. Maybe recheck you're design ? And if that's unavoidable, try to do this not very often, because it breaks the purpose of multithreading